# How to Change Date with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to change 3 datepicker dates on just one click on 1 datepicker. But each of 3 datepicker has their own add date number value in hidden. I'm using jquery datetimepicker.js.

For example:

```
   //Below date picker show today date, and When it is change the date then the 2 below date picker date will increase date as their hidden value number.
<input type="text" class="add_date form-control" name="add_date[]" value="" required autocomplete="off" onkeydown="OnKeyDown(event)">

<input type="text" class="nsend_date form-control" name="send_date[]" value="" required autocomplete="off" onkeydown="OnKeyDown(event)">

    //The above datepicker have to added date as the below hidden field value(3).

<input type="hidden" value="3" id="date_add" name="needed_plan_date[]">



<input type="text" class="nsend_date form-control" name="send_date[]" value="" required autocomplete="off" onkeydown="OnKeyDown(event)">

    //The above datepicker have to added date as the below hidden field value(2).

<input type="hidden" value="2" id="date_add" name="needed_plan_date[]">
```

Comment: Please also post your JS code (where you're attempting to achieve what you've described) and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: to change the date, you click on a date in a datepicker - hope that helps

Comment: Mr.Jaromanda - Yep as you say is yes. But I want to make change the date from 2 datepicker by clicking from another 1 datepicker.

 But the 1st two datepicker has hidden value number (2) or (3). I want to use that number to increase date. 

For example: today date is 23/12/2016. Then when i click on 2nd another date picker then the 1st two date picker increase their date as hidden value. like that 26/12/2016 and 25/12/2016.

Answer (score 0):

The propriety to change a date is `$('#IdOfDatepicker').datepicker('SetDate', Var contening date);` it's easy to increment the days of date with an easy function of Java that at the moment i don't remember, to get the value of input box you should use `document.getElementById('IdOfElement').value`
I Hope that you are looking for this

Comment: And you must change the id of elements, every element has got its id, else if you can't set its value